# matching on some values but not others in nested dict

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
{108: {Wallmart: {'ca': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 204: {Wallmart: {'ny': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 205: {Wallmart: {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 110: {CVS: {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 184: {Wallmart: {'fl': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 185: {Wallmart: {'fl': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 105: {Wallmart: {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 497: {Wallmart: {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 400: {RiteAid: {'dc': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 406: {RidaAid: {'dc': {'geat': 'busy'}}},
 367: {Other: {'tx': {'bad': 'busy'}}}}
```

What I need to do is iterate over this data and find the keys with the same state but different shop names.  For example, with the data provided above the output should end up with just:

```
 204: {Wallmart: {'ny': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 205: {Wallmart: {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 110: {CVS: {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
```

Because the states (ny) match but the shop name (wallmart, cvs) do not match.

I'd then do a `user_input` asking to user of this code to specify if they want "Wallmart" or "CVS". That part I'm fine with but pulling the information out of this dictionary is proving difficult

Comment: Neither here nor there, but Walmart just has one "L".

Comment: But Walmart occured twice as opposed to what you want..

Comment: Is this dict under your control or is it an input? If you have control, consider changing it's structure to something that will be much easier to parse. Something like: `{108: {'name': 'Walmart', 'state': 'ny', 'status': 'good'}, ...}`. Then your task is simply `k, d for k, d in data.items() if v['state'] == 'ny'`...

Comment: Create a new dictionary that "inverts" your current dict. You want a mapping from state to list of stores. Then if that list has more than one store, you can ask your user to select one. A defaultdict is very useful in this case.

Comment: please clarify your intent, perhaps you meant you want all the objects that are from a given state?

Comment: I want to know if a state has different stores.  So in this example NY has Wallmart & CVS.  I don't care that Wallmart appears twice in NY

Comment: The dict is not under my control.  it is data pulled from another system

Comment: So, basically, for every state that has more than one store you want a list of these stores?

Comment: Ok so this is a grouping by state procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dict's structure is:

```
{id: {name: {state: {level: status}}}, ...}
```

It would be easier to work with a structure like:

```
{state1: {id: {store_dict}, ...}, state2: {...}, ...}
```

For this conversion we need to get the state which is done by taking the only key in each level and using it to access the next. We will also use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to dynamically create the list for each state:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

states =defaultdict(list)
for _id, store in data.items():
    name = list(store.keys())[0]
    state = list(store[name].keys())[0]
    states[state][_id] = store
```

And now you can simply access `states` with the state you want. So this is an example printing function:

```
def print_state(state):
    for _id, store in states[state].items():
        print(_id, store, sep=': ')
```

And use it:

```
>>> print_state('ny')
204: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'good': 'busy'}}}
205: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}}
110: {'CVS': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}}
```

Comment: the issue with this is that the state might be anything, so doing `if 'ny' in store[name]` won't work if the state is something else

Answer (score 0):

I tried to partly tackle the question by utilising `DataFrame` as below -

The idea is the use `recursion` and flatten the dictionary into `res`

Then use a sliding window of 5 to extract 5 elements consecutively - `divide_chunks_sliding`

```
d = {108: {'Wallmart': {'ca': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 204: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 205: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 110: {'CVS': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 184: {'Wallmart': {'fl': {'great': 'busy'}}},
 185: {'Wallmart': {'fl': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 105: {'Wallmart': {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 497: {'Wallmart': {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}},
 400: {'RiteAid': {'dc': {'good': 'busy'}}},
 406: {'RidaAid': {'dc': {'geat': 'busy'}}},
 367: {'Other': {'tx': {'bad': 'busy'}}}}


def recur_dict(inp,res=[]):
    for x in inp:
         if isinstance(inp[x],dict):
             res += [x]
             recur_dict(inp[x],res)
         else:
             res += [x]
             res += [inp[x]]
    return res

def divide_chunks_sliding(in_arr,chunk):
    n = len(in_arr)
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        i += chunk
        yield in_arr[i-chunk:i]

##### Divide Chunks Usage Example #####
>>> print(list(divide_chunks_sliding([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],2)))

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Leveraging the above functions, `df` is created and merged back with self on `store`

```
res = recur_dict(d)
values = list(divide_chunks_sliding(res,5))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=['Key','Brand','store','review','flag'])

df_merge = pd.merge(df,df[['store','Brand']],on=['store'],suffixes=['_Self_Left','_Self_Right'])


>>> print(df_merge[df_merge['Brand_Self_Left'] != df_merge['Brand_Self_Right']])

    Key Brand_Self_Left store review  flag Brand_Self_Right
3   204        Wallmart    ny   good  busy              CVS
6   205        Wallmart    ny  great  busy              CVS
7   110             CVS    ny  great  busy         Wallmart
8   110             CVS    ny  great  busy         Wallmart
19  400         RiteAid    dc   good  busy          RidaAid
20  406         RidaAid    dc   geat  busy          RiteAid
```

`df_merge` will contain all the rows with the same `store` and different `Brand` , however converting it back to the original structure is pending

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is group your data according to states.

```
result = {}
for iD, shops in data.items():
    for shop, states in shops.items():
        for state, _ in states.items():
            if not state in result:
                result[state] = [{iD: shops}]
            else:
                result[state].append({iD: shops})
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
{'ca': [{108: {'Wallmart': {'ca': {'good': 'busy'}}}}],
 'ny': [{204: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'good': 'busy'}}}},
        {205: {'Wallmart': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}}},
        {110: {'CVS': {'ny': {'great': 'busy'}}}}],
 'fl': [{184: {'Wallmart': {'fl': {'great': 'busy'}}}},
        {185: {'Wallmart': {'fl': {'bad': 'busy'}}}}],
 'ga': [{105: {'Wallmart': {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}}},
        {497: {'Wallmart': {'ga': {'bad': 'busy'}}}}],
 'dc': [{400: {'RiteAid': {'dc': {'good': 'busy'}}}},
        {406: {'RidaAid': {'dc': {'geat': 'busy'}}}}],
 'tx': [{367: {'Other': {'tx': {'bad': 'busy'}}}}]}
```